# Listar quantidade de arquivos em uma pasta

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

Estou trabalhando em um pequeno sistema e estou utilizando web por N motivos, fácil de personalizar, trabalhar com tela cheia (f11), tudo está fluindo muito bem. Cheguei em uma parte que preciso listar a quantidade de arquivos que estão dentro de um determinado diretório e vi que é impossível fazer com JavaScript mas que posso utilizar Node.js.. Porém, acho tão ruim ter que instalar o Node.js somente para executar 4 linhas de código, vai quebrar a minha ideia até deixar o sistema super leve.

Existe alguma forma de contornar isso? Alguma forma de pegar a quantidade de arquivos que estão dentro de um diretório?

Obrigado.

(Apenas confirmando, se eu desenvolvo utilizando o Node.js o cliente também vai precisar ter ele instalado, correto?)

Comment: Se a distribuição para o seu cliente for offline, sim, caso contrario é possível hospedar em um servidor facilmente, e seu cliente não irá precisar do node. Em relação ao desempenho, creio que não iria decair muito com node, até acho uma boa ideia pois ele foi inicialmente projetado para manipulação de arquivos no servidor, e faz isso muito rapidamente e sim, esse tipo de contagem só é possível com uma linguagem de servidor.

Comment: Você pode migrar sua aplicação web para o framework [electron](https://electronjs.org/) como um app que tem maior acesso à máquina e trabalhar sem precisar instalar o node.js na máquina do cliente pra usar o app, aqui um exemplo: [electron-file-explorer](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/file-explorer)

Comment: Esqueci de citar, sim a aplicação precisa trabalhar offline. Pois é, mas imagina, ter que instalar 15mb só para rodar 4 linhas, pois a única coisa que está faltando mesmo é automatizar isso de pegar a quantidade de arquivos para saber o número de páginas que ele irá executar. :/ 

Eu imagino que em JavaScript não da, estou mais tentando recorrer se existe algum outro modo.

Comment: Não conheço esse electron, não entendi muito bem o funcionamento dele mas vou ler a respeito.

Comment: O electron basicamente é um browser com node embutido. É feito para se criar aplicações desktop usando tecnologia de web (html, css, js + node). Parece exatamente o seu caso.

Comment: Olha, legal em cara.. Vou ver isso agora! Valeu mesmo pela ajuda, acredito que irá resolver meu problema.